# Can't do division

Tags: c#

```
int h1 = 2;
int d1 = 4;
decimal c1 = d1/(d1+h1);
Console.WriteLine("{0:F9}", c1);
```

Console shows 0,00000000000, but I expected to see 0,6666666 and maybe 7 in the end. What's the problem? I tried different methods, but always see 0,00000000...

Comment: "What's the problem?" Your expectation. The result is [correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20382174/96780).

Comment: You should pick up a book on datatypes in C# :)

Comment: Why so many down-votes, this seem like a legit question and an easy rookie mistake.

Comment: The moral of the story here is not expressed in either answer. **Do not mix floating point calculations with integer calculations in the first place**. They are completely different kinds of math. It is unfortunate that the language allows this at all; I note that it disallows mixing binary and decimal floating point math without explicit casts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because you're doing an integer division. You need to cast one value to decimal in order to do a decimal division :

```
int h1 = 2;
int d1 = 4;
decimal c1 = (decimal)d1 / (d1 + h1);
```

Basically, you can translate the current problematic behavior as:

```
decimal c1 = (decimal)(d1 / (d1 + h1));
decimal c1 = (decimal)(4 / (2 + 4));
decimal c1 = (decimal)(4 / 6);
decimal c1 = (decimal)(0); <-- Integer division
decimal c1 = 0m;
```

That's why you need either the numerator or denominator to be explicitly a decimal already.

Also, where you do the casting it is totally irrelevant, you just need to trigger the decimal division. Those 4 lines have exactly the same result :

```
decimal c1 = (decimal)d1 / (d1 + h1);
decimal c2 = d1 / ((decimal)d1 + h1);
decimal c3 = d1 / (d1 + (decimal)h1);
decimal c4 = d1 / (decimal)(d1 + h1);
```

Comment: Just forgot about casting after a couple of other programming languages... Thanks

Comment: The first and fourth rely for their correctness on the fact that integer addition always agrees with decimal addition. The best practice here would be for h1 and d1 to be decimals in the first place rather than relying on the cast.

Answer (score 1):

your `d1` and `h1` are int's so the result is first casted to `int` and after it is assigned to c1, casting `d1` to decimal will solve your problem